# What is the job of the "end" argument in the print function?

Tags: python

for example in this code below the with the end the integers stay on the same line but without the it does not.

```
num = 5
for i in range(1, num +1):
  for j in range(num, i-1, -1):
  print(j, end="")
print()
```

Comment: `help(print)` not working?

Comment: This is unrelated to the `for` loop...

Comment: The question contains the answer!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because really, stack overflow is better than that.

Comment: For what it's worth, although you can do `print("hello world!")` in Python2, `print("hello world!", end="")` throws a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `end` statement for printing in Python allows the programmer to define a custom ending character for each `print` call other than the default `\n`

For instance, if you have a function that is to print all values within a list on the same line, you do:

```
def value(l):
    for items in l:
        print(l, end=' ')
```

So if the list argued to this function contains the values `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, it will print them in this manner: `1 2 3 4`. If this new ending character parameter was not defined they would be printed:

```
1
2
3
4
```

The same principle applies for ANY value you provide for the `end` option.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, the default ist `end='\n'` for the print function which is a newline after the string is printed.

To suppress this newline, one can set `end=''` so that the next print starts in the same line.

This is unrelated to the `for` loop.